# wp7 how to add a pre install message

Tags: deployment, c#-3.0, installation, messagebox, windows-phone-7

I want to add a pre install messagebox in my wp7 application, like in most of the application on market place.

e.g., my message :

'This application required your location services access, if you don't want to allow app to use it, click cancel otherwise allow'

if user choose allow then application installs otherwise it doesn't install

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you set that capability in the app's manifest (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Capabilities) that it will ask this question on install, but I'm not certain. Curious to know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

These messages are created by the Marketplace / install routine based on the capabilities requested by your app.  You can't change them.

For example, if your app manifest says the app will use location services, the install routine prompts the user with a default message asking if they want to allow access.